# Prepend a text to a file in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to pre-pend a text to a file using a Makefile. The following bash command works in terminal:

```
echo -e "DATA-Line-1\n$(cat input)" > input
```

But when I put the above command in a Makefile, it does not work:

```
copyHeader:
    @echo -e "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE \n$(cat input)" > input
```

I guess $(cat input) does not work as expected in the Makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend sed for prepending a line of text to a file. The `i` command is kind of a pain; some clever use of the hold space does the same thing in a more complicated but less troublesome way:

```
copyHeader:
    sed -i "" '1{h;s/.*/NEW FIRST LINE/;G;}' input
```

<strike>But if you want to do it your way, I think an extra '$' will do the trick:</strike>

copyHeader:
        @echo -e "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE \n$$(cat input)" > input

**EDIT:** Thanks to MadScientist for pointing out that this method (using `$(cat input)`) is unreliable.

Comment: the sed command gives me error: sed: can't read 1{h;s/.*/NEW FIRST LINE/;G;}: No such file or directory

Comment: The second example cannot work, in general.  It's undefined whether the redirection will happen (causing `input` to be truncated to an empty file) before or after running the `cat input` command.  Plus, this is kind of inefficient (unless you know `input` is always small.  And `echo -e` is not portable.  The only safe way to do it is with a temporary file: `echo 'DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE' > input.$$$$; cat input >> input.$$$$; mv -f input.$$$$ input`

Comment: @ManiAm: Which version of sed are you using? Try `sed '1{h;s/.*/NEW FIRST LINE/;G;}' input` on the command line and see if it works, and we can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

A `file` function was added to make in 4.0, which as of 4.2 can also read from files

The newline is a little bit hacky but this can be accomplished with make alone:

```
define n


endef

copyHeader:
    $(file > input,DATA-Line-1$n$(file < input))
```

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with this for a while (accepted answer does not work with the sed that comes with OSX 10.12, make was too old for the file manipulation options), I settled on the following (ugly) solution:

```
echo "DATA-Line-1" > line.tmp
mv input input.tmp
cat line.tmp input.tmp > input
rm input.tmp line.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$ cat test
this
is
a
test

$ sed -i "1i new first line" test

$ cat test
new first line
this
is
a
test
```

Comment: This is working ok so far for me. But it doesn't work on empty files? any ideas?